# Cannot pass any ENV variables from docker to Node process.env

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm struggling to pass any env variables from docker to my node process in my container.
When printing in the `index.js` the `process.env` keys, here is what I get:

```
    SUDO_GID: 0
    SUDO_UID: 0
    SUDO_USER: root
    SUDO_COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/node index.js
    ...
```

I should get at least the `MY_ENV=text` I try to pass.
Here are the different things I've tried so far:

- The classic way:

`docker run -e MY_ENV=text mytestcontainer`

Here is the code I actually run, in case something I don't see "kill" somehow the process.env:

`docker run --privileged -u root -v /sys:/sys -v /dev/mem:/dev/mem -e MY_ENV=text mytestcontainer`

- The classic way bis:

`docker run --env-file ./.env mytestcontainer`

- I even try directly in my `Dockerfile` via `ENV`! and nothing is passed to the process:

```
FROM balenalib/raspberrypi3-node

ENV MY_ENV=text

ARG api_port=7070
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends pigpio
RUN sudo apt-get install build-essential
RUN sudo apt-get install python
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /opt/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install

COPY . /opt/app
RUN npm rebuild pigpio
EXPOSE $api_port
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

- I also tried via docker-compose, but of course, if `docker run` does not work, why would docker-compose work!

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: mytestcontainer
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "7070:7070"
    volumes:
      - /sys:/sys
      - /dev/mem:/dev/mem
    environment:
      MY_ENV: text

  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "35432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: testUser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_SCHEMA: test

volumes:
  db:
```

The weird thing is that even in the Postgres image, none of the env variables are passed

For info, here is my `index.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config()

console.log('env variables: ')
Object.entries(process.env).forEach(kv => {
  console.log(kv[0] + ': ' + kv[1])
})
```

- When I run my code directly, not in a docker container, all my env variables are present in the process.env
- When I get inside the container, I can echo the variable:

```
# echo $MY_ENV
text
```

So I thought that could be something related to my system, but I tried to run everything on sudo, and on a different machine (a raspberry pi) and nothing differ. Same issue.

Any help or idea would be much appreciated :)

Comment: can you try with `require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') })`?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see your comment, have a look to my auto-answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that might help other people in my case (pretty new in docker)
The issue was a difference of access rights, due to my starting script in the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "sudo node index.js"
 },
```

As you can see, I was using sudo. If I remove that, I get all my env variables in the `process.env`
So it might means that the docker user is different from the node process.